Meta Marketing API - Keep User's session active
We have a Facebook App created with a dummy User to manage Ads and Audience to which it has access to. Unfortunately it's complicated at the moment to create it under a proper company's User, because we manage many Pages and Clients and there is a lot of burocracy.
In any case, the Access Token associated to this Facebook App works fine and has its live span set to 90 days: the trouble is that after 30 days of the dummy User's inactivity on Facebook, the user get dissociated from the Facebook App. This results in our automated refreshToken call to fail.
We have to manually login and re-connect the User to the Application.
In fact, the APIs calls we do for our business purpose aren't enough / aren't considered as User's actions: this sound both fair and unintuitive.
Is there a knowkn way or an API call (even as simple as "list your own feed") to keep the User's session active?
Thank you in advance for any tips.
